# Reset 'Friendly Name' certificate property using PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, certificate

I need to have a certificate's `Friendly Name` set to an empty value so in Certificate Console `Friendly Name` column would display `<None>`.
Using this code all I could get is just empty value in the column, not `<None>` I need.

```
 gci "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" | ? {$_.Subject -like "CN=mycer*"} | % { $_.FriendlyName = '' }
```

I also tried `$_.FriendlyName = $null` which made no difference.

Strange thing - when I clear `Friendly Name` using console then from Powershell's perspective the value is `''` as the following statement produces `True`: `write-host ($_.FriendlyName -eq '')`. However, the `''`' value applied vice a versa doesn't provide the expected result.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE and ANSWER:
As [Kory Gill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5329137/kory-gill) suggested in comments, *certutil.exe* is indeed the way to get what I need. 
Having created an `clear.inf` file with content below

```
[Version]
Signature = "$Windows NT$"

[Properties]
11 =
```

and executed `certutil.exe -repairstore -user my "serial number" clear.inf` I managed to reset `Friendly Name` to `<None>` value.

Comment: Why don't you just set the `FriendlyName` to `<None>`?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 because it is another `<None>`. It'll appear not as empty value in property editor but as `<None>`, which is not what I need to have.

Comment: So try setting `$_.FriendlyName = $null` instead of an empty string? Or maybe you need to be using `Set-ItemProperty`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician `$null` doesn't make any difference - I checked it before posting. As for `Set-ItemProperty` - worths a try, will check tomorrow when I am back in the office.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician `Set-ItemProperty` doesn't work at all. `Cannot use interface. The IPropertyCmdletProvider interface is not supported by this provider`

Comment: perhaps use certutil.exe http://ucready.com/change-friendly-name-of-a-x-509-certificate/

Comment: @KoryGill please make your comment answer so I could mark it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to the PowerShell cmdlet for managing certificates, which may have issues with some properties, one can use certutil.exe as well to manage certs. This is similar to using robocopy.exe instead of Copy-File. Use the tools that give you the desired results...

[This link](http://ucready.com/change-friendly-name-of-a-x-509-certificate/) shows an example of how to use certutil to change the friendly name.

Example usage from that page is:

```
certutil.exe -repairstore my "{serialnumber}" "change-friendly-name.inf"
```

where the inf file looks like:

```
[Version]
Signature = "$Windows NT$"
[Properties]
11 = "{text}new friendly name"
```

See also [certutil reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732443.aspx).